# Python counting DNA nucleotides

Tags: python, string

> **Problem**
>
> A string is simply an ordered collection of symbols selected from some
>   alphabet and formed into a word; the length of a string is the number
>   of symbols that it contains.
>
> An example of a length 21 DNA string (whose alphabet contains the
>   symbols `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, and `'T'`) is `"ATGCTTCAGAAAGGTCTTACG."`
>
> **Given:** A DNA string s
>
> of length at most 1000 nt.
>
> **Return:** Four integers (separated by spaces) counting the respective number of times that the symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'
>   occur in s
>
> **Sample Dataset**
>
> ```
> AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 20 12 17 21
> ```

can someone help me figure this code for python 3 on a mac? I am sorry I am totally not accustomed with python

Comment: `import collections; counts = collections.Counter(s); print(counts['A'],counts['C'],counts['G'],counts['T'])`

Comment: Please try to at least google before asking. This is one of the easiest tasks you can do in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy.

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
a = Counter(s)
print (a)
```

Counter({'T': 21, 'A': 20, 'G': 17, 'C': 12})

Comment: First, `[*s]` is totally unecessary, *`str` objects are iterable directly*. Second, this is clearly a duplicate, please vote to close as duplicate rather than answering.